# Create a has_one that returns an object of the same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I want to create a has_one that will return the active user, I have tried the following

```
has_one :active_user, lambda { where(status: :active) }, class_name: 'User'
```

gives an error

```
column users.user_id does not exist
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. A `has_one` association is always the inverse of a `belongs_to` association and you need an actual column in on the table where you store the assocation. See https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1):

"Self Joins" does not make sense in this context.
You can get a good understanding about self joins [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins):

I recommend to use "scope" in rails:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_active_status, -> { where(status: :active) }
end

@active_users = User.with_active_status
```